# Is there a publicly available video that shows Ali Erdoğan instructing a police official to abuse detainees?

Tags: turkey

The Wikipedia page for the [2013 corruption scandal in Turkey](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2013_corruption_scandal_in_Turkey#Other_controversies) says:

> On 24 December, another video began to circulate that shows Ali Erdoğan, nephew and bodyguard of Prime Minister Erdoğan, instructing a police commissioner to abuse the detainees who had protested his uncle and hurling insults at him when he refuses.

[Google video search](https://www.google.com/search?q=video%20began%20to%20circulate%20that%20shows%20Ali%20Erdo%C4%9Fan%2C%20nephew%20and%20bodyguard%20of%20Prime%20Minister%20Erdo%C4%9Fan%2C%20instructing%20a%20police%20commissioner%20to%20abuse%20the%20detainees&oq=video%20began%20to%20circulate%20that%20shows%20Ali%20Erdo%C4%9Fan%2C%20nephew%20and%20bodyguard%20of%20Prime%20Minister%20Erdo%C4%9Fan%2C%20instructing%20a%20police%20commissioner%20to%20abuse%20the%20detainees&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8#safe=off&tbm=vid&q=%20Ali%20Erdo%C4%9Fan%20Instructing%20a%20police%20commissioner%20to%20abuse%20the%20detainees) doesn't list any relevant video. Is there a publicly available video  that shows Ali Erdoğan instructing a police official to abuse detainees?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The video [Turkey PM Erdoğan's Nephew Threatens Police To Torture Teacher Under Arrest](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LtfnEzWmgLU) was published 23:59:24 on Dec 23, 2013, so I think it's the video you're looking for.

The video quality is horrible, but it at least contains a transcript in English (warning: language):

> ALİ ERDOĞAN: man .... still you say, You cannot let them sit.
>   POLICEMAN: man ...There in nothing like that I cannot let them sit.
>   ALİ ERDOĞAN: You cannot let this man sit down.
>   POLICEMAN: why i cannot let him sit
>   ALİ ERDOĞAN: you will keep him on his feet
>   POLICEMAN: everybody that comes to a police office can sit down
>   ALİ ERDOĞAN: you will keep him on his feet
>   POLICEMAN: That is inappropriate
>   ALİ ERDOĞAN: he had been insulted the prime minister, so you will keep him on his feet, but you had let him sit down.
>   ALİ ERDOĞAN: you are such a man, so I SHIT ON YOUR MOUTH, here in front of everybody
>   POLICEMAN: Mr. would you like a thing to be done to you...(that you don't want)
>   ALİ ERDOĞAN: This is Prime Minister, not an ordinary man
>   POLICEMAN: You did it for yourselves, go away
>   ALİ ERDOĞAN: twerp, I, I KILL you
>   POLICEMAN: what is this, what does it mean that i will keep him on his feet
>   ALİ ERDOĞAN: you will keep him on his feet
>   i will keep him on his feet hah
>   ALİ ERDOĞAN: immodest man.
>   ALİ ERDOĞAN: he says he lets him sit down. FUCK OFF. man he cannot let, he will keep him on feet.
>   OTHER BODYGUARDS: brother Ali, brother Ali ok...